# Flow when block is created

Tags: blockchain

I believe I know what is required to create block.

- 1.get previous hash(previous block is published)
- 2.collect transactions
- 3.proof of work(mining)
- 4.timestamped
- 5.audit by other nodes

Please tell me in what order these are done.

Comment: This was helpful for me. (https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12564/can-a-miner-set-the-exact-timestamp-of-a-block)

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I see you already have one answer. You may also find the linked question above of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is 1, 2, 3, 5. There is no timestamping; the block itself provides timestamping via the proof of work.

Also, the step 3 is not 'mining', the whole process is what is called mining.